# NGINX load balance on two tomcats which runs without context-path

Tags: nginx

I have two applications runs on tomcat without context path ( i.e http://localhost:8080/ and http://localhost:8081). These are two different applications, for ex application runs on 8080 do authentication work and application runs on 8081 do some batch operation with database. I need to load balance to these two instances ( using port ). How can i achieve this without modifying applications to have a context path. My configurations are

```
upstream serviceone {
   server host1:8080;
   server host2:8080;
}
upstream servicetwo {
   server host1:8081;
   server host2:8081;
}

# This is for serviceone which is my authentication service but runs without context path . i.e this runs on http://localhost:8080/
location / {
   proxy_pass http://serviceone;
}

# This is my batch operation service which also runs without context path. i.e http://localhost:8081
location / {
   proxy_pass http://servicetwo;
}
```

I'm using nginx opensource edition.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is the problem?

Comment: You can put everything in upstream serviceone (4 hosts) and remove the second location  .

Comment: there are two completely different services running on port 8080 and 8081. Currently they are distinguish by calling service only using ports. Would having one upstream for two application solve this ? I mean how NGINX route traffic comes to / then forward it to 8080 or 8081.